# How to get email events using php curl with mailgun API

Tags: php, api, curl, mailgun

I am working on getting email events using a mailgun API request in php using curl.

I have tried the below code for sending the php curl request:

```
          $params = array(
                'begin'        => 'Fri, 3 May 2013 09:00:00 -0000',
                'ascending'    => 'yes',
                'limit'        =>  2,
                'pretty'       => 'yes',
                'recipient'    => 'myemailaddress@gmail.com'
          );
          $ch = curl_init();

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:MY_API_KEY_HERE');
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/MY_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE/events");
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          $result=json_decode($result);
```

This command returns email events but not according to the specified parameters.

It is ignoring `$params` in the curl post fields option.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');` tells cURL to send a GET request. POST fields are only used when you send a POST request. As per https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#query-options you're supposed to send your parameters a URL parameters on the querystring.

Comment: But I want to pass parameters as https://api.mailgun.net/v3/My_Domain_Name/events?begin=Fri, 3 May 2013 09:00:00 -0000&ascending=yes&limit=25&pretty=yes&recipient=testemail@gmail.com    so as you can see there is some problem with begin parameter which I want to send as mentioned in this url

Comment: I think you would need to URL-encode the date so the spaces (and any other special characters) in the date string are properly converted to the encoded representation. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php . You should url-encode the other values individually as well. See here for more general information about URL-encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding